# Connection Error connection count of 0 does not meet required minimum of 1

Tags: verification, system-verilog

I am getting an error.  I connected my scoreboard's `vip_export` port which is an analysis port with the observer port of my usb agent in the `connect_phase`.  I even new the `vip_export` in the new phase of scoreboard.

I am getting this `UVM_INFO` which I haven't been able to understand.

`UVM_INFO /h/tool_linux/synopsys/vcs/2012.09/etc/uvm-1.1/base/uvm_resource_db.svh(129) @ 0.000 ns: reporter [CFGDB/GET] Configuration 'uvm_test_top.mss1_tb_env.usb_scoreboard.vip_export.check_connection_relationships' (type logic signed[4095:0]) read by uvm_test_top.mss1_tb_env.usb_scoreboard.vip_export = null (failed lookup)`

Comment: @RossRoggers i was reading about your script which highlight different text in log file.can you please elaborate more.i would like to use it for my UVM base log file.

Comment: Hey Vjain419.  I use [my terminal highlighter](https://code.google.com/p/hi-terminal-text-highlighter/) _all_ the time at work.  You give it a regular expression and the colors you'd like to see strings matching that regex on the Linux terminal and you simply pipe your log file through the filter.  If you need to explore all the output, you pipe it into `less -R` so that the color escape sequences are interpreted as colors.  It makes the errors and warnings pop out from the log.  You can make a particular filter an alias in the shell or a shell script so others can reuse your filters.

Comment: its sound great...i will definatly like to try it...please tell me how  do i install it in my login and specially want to highlight for UVM_ERROR ;)

Comment: [Installation instructions are here.](https://code.google.com/p/hi-terminal-text-highlighter/#Installation_Pre-requisites)

Comment: Thanks :) will get back to you of I have any issue

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I used `uvm_analysis_export` instead of `uvm_analysis_imp` in the scoreboard file.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to connect uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo to the uvm_analysis_export